# Return C++ char to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have a C++ project in which I have to return some variables from C++ to C#.

These char variables are in the main program:

char test1[MAX_Q_LEN], test2[MAX_Q_LEN], test3[MAX_Q_LEN];

After I finish doing something with these variables in my C program, I have to return the values of these variables in a C# program.

**ReturnChar.h**

```
extern "C" RETURNCHAR_API TCHAR* __cdecl testString();
```

**ReturnChar.cpp**

```
extern "C" RETURNCHAR_API TCHAR* testString()
{
return ;
}
```

**TestImport C#**

```
static class TestImport
{
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr testString(); 
}


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
public MainWindow()
{
try
{
InitializeComponent();
textBox1.Text = ReturnSomething()
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
}
private static string ReturnSomething()
{
IntPtr t = TestImport.testString();
String result = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(t);
}
```

I tried with the above approach but I am not able to find out how to return the above char values. Also, this should not be an independent function because the values shoud be fetched only after executing the main which will give the right values in these variables.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest a solution which would require you to change function signature to this:

```
extern "C" int __cdecl testString(char *output, int outputSize);
```

That is, pass an allocated buffer as the first argument to the function which will hold the output, and pass the size of the buffer as the second argument.

Note that I mention the return type of the function as `int`. It is because you could return the output *actual* size from the function, and  the caller can interpret this value to confirm that `outputSize` value was large enough to hold the output string. For example, you could implement `testString()` as:

```
 int testString(char *output, int outputSize)
 {
    std::string const & s = getString();
    if ( s.size() <= outputSize )
    {
        std::strncpy(output, s.c_str(), s.size());
        return s.size(); //return the actual size of output
    }
    else //means s.size() > outputSize, i.e outputSize is smaller than required!
    {
        std::strncpy(output, s.c_str(), outputSize);
        return s.size(); //return what is required (the actual size of output)!
    }
 }
```

Then in C# code, do this:

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int testString(out StringBuilder output, int outputSize);
```

And call it as:

```
private static string ReturnSomething()
{
   int bufferSize = 100;
   StringBuilder buffer= new StringBuilder(bufferSize);
   int outputSize = TestImport.testString(buffer, bufferSize);
   if ( outputSize < bufferSize )  //output bufferSize was sufficient
   {
        return buffer.ToString();
   }
   else //output bufferSize was insufficient 
   {
        //retry!
        bufferSize = outputSize;
        buffer = new StringBuilder(bufferSize); //reallocate!
        outputSize = TestImport.testString(buffer, bufferSize); 
        if ( outputSize <= bufferSize )
             return buffer.ToString();
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("PANIC");
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: As i remember CLR will use `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem()` method to deallocate string in that case, so `CoTaskMemAlloc` should be used to allocate that on c++ side (`new` can have its own realization in our case so managed side won't be able to deallocate that) am i right ?

Comment: @Nawaz: I tried changing the StringBuilder, but it is not giving me any output in the textbox. Neither it isthrowing any exception/error. My full code: C# file: http://pastebin.com/c0YD33C8 , `ReutnrChar.cpp` http://pastebin.com/1dQkkzus , `ReturnChar.h` http://pastebin.com/VvZv9EHP

Comment: @Cipher: Why are you returning a pointer to a local object? In the function you declare a local array, and you're returning it, but do you realize the local object is destroyed when the function returns? So I would say, try this : `char *data = new char[13]; strcpy(data, "Hello World!"); return data;`

Comment: @Nawaz: How will I return `test1[MAX_Q_LEN]` variable which has a large length? Should I be allocating new `data` variable for all these variables to return from `C++ exported` variables?

Comment: @Nawaz: I started getting this error on changing to allocating a new `data` variable. http://i.imgur.com/eD5WN.png

Comment: @Cipher: Put a break point, and see what the function returns.

Comment: Tried that. Looks like it's not going into the function or something :-/
ReturnChar.cpp: http://pastebin.com/nnzmfCn3 ,
ReturnChar.h: http://pastebin.com/zsWcsLtw ,
ReturnChar C#: http://pastebin.com/J0jSi0uY

Comment: @BenVoigt: Doesn't CLR handle the memory thingy? I don't know much about pinvoke.

Comment: @Nawaz: How can the CLR possibly know how to free the memory?  You didn't tell it anywhere.  And `new[]`/`delete[]` isn't even compatible between different DLLs built with the same C++ compiler and static linking, nevermind between different languages.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Ohh.. I've no idea about that. So what should be the solution? Could you post a solution so I learn something new today?

Comment: @Nawaz: Two ways.  (1) Caller allocates, this method is used by most of the WIn32 API and is really easy to get right on both ends.  (2) Agree on an allocator.  For example, DanNsk's answer agrees that the function will use `SysAllocString` and the caller (p/invoke) must use `SysFreeString`, because these are the functions that every `BSTR` uses.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Can you explain the first approach? How can the caller allocate the memory to used by the callee? And how would the callee use that memory?

Comment: @Nawaz: With a .NET caller and C++ callee, that'd look something like `StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(1000); cppfunc(result, result.Length);`  And the C++ function would be `void cppfunc(char* out_buff, int out_buf_length);`  An easy example of this is the Win32 function `GetSystemDirectory`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Ohh.. that is the approach I've used in my project (*that is why I said in my answer I've done similar thing, and it works; I just didn't know that it just works only for **out** parameter*). Thanks for explaining that. Now I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: @Nawaz: That is really an *inout* parameter, which is what makes it work.  The caller sets up the buffer before the call, so the function has memory to work with.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, I understand it. Also, completed with editing my post. Let me know if it is correct now.

Comment: @Nawaz: For example, the C++ function has two identical `return` statements, and the whole `if` isn't even needed, just always take the second path.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think `if-else` is needed, because `std::strncpy` is different in both cases; however, `return` can be written just once, but I wrote is twice so that I could write comment for each, something which, I hope, would be helpful for the OP to understand what each branch actually does. Once he understands it, he may improve on this.

Comment: @Nawaz: Passing `outputSize` is fine in both cases, that's guaranteed by `strncpy`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Does `std::strncpy` also check for null character?

Comment: Please take extended discussions to one of the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) instead of using comments.

Comment: @Nawaz - actually you still have `StringBuilder` set as `out` (modifier which you don't need here) and it basically won't compile since you're correctly trying to call that w/o `out` a bit later.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite big c++ spec, but maybe to use bstrs in c++

```
_bstr_t text("saasas");
return text.Detach();
```

and for c# parameter

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
```

or to pass `StringBuilder` to your c++ func with some preallocated capacity

Comment: Can you please elaborate with the prototypes of the functions and using the char variables instead of fixed text "saasas" ?

Comment: Just found several samples here http://goo.gl/A5yWE, that looks much better than description i can make you here.